# How do I sort an array so that the indexes match another sorted array again PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have data added to arrays in a loop - e.g. $name is added to $names[] and $address is added to $addresses[] for each one. I then sort one of them by ascending numbers, but I don't know how to sort the other ones to match the indexes for the sorted one again? It is a bit complicated. Does anyone know how I could match them again? Thanks in advance

```
if(round($distance1) < 30) {
    array_push($distarray, round($distance1));
    array_push($names, $nameX2);
    array_push($profos, $profoX);
    if($typeX == "") {
        $typeX = "Unknown";

    }
    array_push($types, $typeX);

    $index += 1;
}

}
sort($distarray);
for($i = 0; $i < count($distarray); $i++) {

    echo '<div id="profile" style="position:relative;top:' . $top . 'px;"><img src="' . $profos[$i] 
        . '" id="imager"></img><div style="font-size:1.2vw;color:#0088ff";">' 
        . $names[$i] . '</div><br><div style="font-size:1.2vw;color:#0B0BBB";">' 
        . $distarray[$i] . 'km from ' . $nameX 
        . ' </div><br><div style="font-size:1.2vw;color:#0088ff";position:relative;left:80px;">' 
        . $typeNum . '</div></div>';
    $top += 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort multiple arrays in php use the `array_multisort` function.
[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is the documentation to this function with an example.